# How Can I Validate Input From User When The Values From Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

i have a sale page where the item and there rate is retrieved from database.
like when i wright a item code it retrieve the item name along with its rate on the text boxes.
now problem is that my user want to change the rate so retrieved from database.
suppose item name is Book and its rate is 100. user want to change the rate from 100 to 101 or 110 0r any value more than 100 or equal to 100.
so my question is this that how can he do it. suppose if he chose 100(which is automatic retrieved from database) or more than 100 he is allowed. and when he chooses or enter value less then 100 an error message get generated. 
give me logic or code how to go for it.
i am using VS 2010 and SQL server 2008.

Comment: Compare the input with 100, and decide the course of action

Comment: yes i have done with the designing and retrieving

Comment: how to do the comparison

Comment: Use a CustomValidator

Comment: @shantanu sinha : can you please post your code so that we can help you out. I see no complications here and have the solution immediatly.

Answer (score 0):

Load the values in Cache. And before saving compare the value user has entered with what you have in cache. You will get your results.

Answer (score 0):

```
When you are going to save data that time you could check like this:



    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(yourtextBoxName.Text)<100)
                {
                  MessageBox.Show("Value is not correct.");
                }         
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding the datafield with the textBox,

You can simply compare the textbox value with the datafield value.